# HttpPost of Microsoft Teams

Tags: http-post, microsoft-teams

Im using webhook to send adaptive card to teams and i put my api (mage pipeline trigger api) as target. so i expect when i click on the button from adaptive card it will trigger the pipeline based on the api. however it keep showing "There was a problem submitting your changes. Try again in a minute." what is the problem?

import requests
import json

## Microsoft Teams incoming webhook URL

webhook_url = "https://interpublic.webhook.office.com/..."

adaptive_card = {
"@type": "MessageCard",
"@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
"themeColor": "0076D7",
"summary": "Request",
"sections": [{
"activityTitle": "Request",
"activitySubtitle": "Task:",
"facts": [{
"name": "Assigned to",
"value": "MR."
}, {
"name": "Due Date",
"value": "2000-09-12"
}],
"markdown": True
}],
"potentialAction": [{
"@type": "ActionCard",
"name": "Approve",
"actions": [{
"@type": "HttpPOST",
"name": "Approve",
"target": "https://mageai."
}]
}, {
"@type": "ActionCard",
"name": "Reject",
"actions": [{
"@type": "HttpPOST",
"name": "Reject",
"target": "https://mageai."
}]
}]
}

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

## Send the adaptive card as a Teams message

response = requests.Post(webhook_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(adaptive_card))

Comment: We already have a bug raised for this issue, we will keep you posted once we have an update. Thank you.